# Flink 1.11 FlinkKafkaConsumer fails to propagate watermarks while Flink 1.12 succeeds

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm seeing some strange behavior. I wrote up some Flink processors using Flink 1.12, and tried to get them working on Amazon EMR. However Amazon EMR only supports Flink 1.11.2 at the moment. When I went to downgrade, I found, inexplicably, that watermarks were no longer propagating.

There is only one partition on the topic, and parallelism is set to 1. Is there something I'm missing here? I feel like I'm going a bit crazy.

Here's the output for Flink 1.12:

```
Topic:input partitions=1
(name=input, internal=false, partitions=(partition=0, leader=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), replicas=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), isr=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)), authorizedOperations=null)
{
  "nodes" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "Source: Custom Source",
    "pact" : "Data Source",
    "contents" : "Source: Custom Source",
    "parallelism" : 1
  }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "type" : "Process",
    "pact" : "Operator",
    "contents" : "Process",
    "parallelism" : 1,
    "predecessors" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "ship_strategy" : "FORWARD",
      "side" : "second"
    } ]
  } ]
}
Topic:input partitions=1
(name=input, internal=false, partitions=(partition=0, leader=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), replicas=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), isr=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)), authorizedOperations=null)
Assigning timestamp 86400000
Source [timestamp=86400000 watermark=-9223372036854775808] test message
Emitting watermark 0
Assigning timestamp 864000000
Source [timestamp=864000000 watermark=0] test message
Emitting watermark 777600000
Assigning timestamp 8640000000
Source [timestamp=8640000000 watermark=777600000] test message
Emitting watermark 8553600000
Assigning timestamp 86400000000
Source [timestamp=86400000000 watermark=8553600000] test message
Emitting watermark 86313600000
Assigning timestamp 9223372036854775807
Source [timestamp=9223372036854775807 watermark=86313600000] test message
Emitting watermark 9223372036768375807
```

And here is the output for Flink 1.11:

```
Topic:input partitions=1
(name=input, internal=false, partitions=(partition=0, leader=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), replicas=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), isr=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)), authorizedOperations=null)
{
  "nodes" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "Source: Custom Source",
    "pact" : "Data Source",
    "contents" : "Source: Custom Source",
    "parallelism" : 1
  }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "type" : "Process",
    "pact" : "Operator",
    "contents" : "Process",
    "parallelism" : 1,
    "predecessors" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "ship_strategy" : "FORWARD",
      "side" : "second"
    } ]
  } ]
}
Topic:input partitions=1
(name=input, internal=false, partitions=(partition=0, leader=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), replicas=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), isr=mycomputer:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)), authorizedOperations=null)
Assigning timestamp 86400000
Source [timestamp=0 watermark=-9223372036854775808] test message
Emitting watermark 0
Assigning timestamp 864000000
Source [timestamp=0 watermark=-9223372036854775808] test message
Emitting watermark 777600000
Assigning timestamp 8640000000
Source [timestamp=0 watermark=-9223372036854775808] test message
Emitting watermark 8553600000
Assigning timestamp 86400000000
Source [timestamp=0 watermark=-9223372036854775808] test message
Emitting watermark 86313600000
Assigning timestamp 9223372036854775807
Source [timestamp=0 watermark=-9223372036854775808] test message
Emitting watermark 9223372036768375807
```

Here's the integration test that exposes it:

```
package mytest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import kafka.server.KafkaConfig;
import kafka.server.KafkaServer;

import kafka.utils.MockTime;
import kafka.utils.TestUtils;

import kafka.zk.EmbeddedZookeeper;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.TimestampAssigner;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.TimestampAssignerSupplier;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.Watermark;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkGenerator;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkGeneratorSupplier;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkOutput;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.JobExecutionResult;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.core.execution.JobClient;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobCancellationException;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.testutils.MiniClusterResourceConfiguration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.ProcessFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.ProcessFunction.Context;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimerService;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer;
import org.apache.flink.test.util.MiniClusterWithClientResource;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreateTopicsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeTopicsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.TopicDescription;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;

import org.junit.*;

public class FailTest {
    public Properties getKafkaConsumerProperties() {
        Properties result = new Properties();
        result.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test-application");
        result.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        result.put("group.id", "0");
        result.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        result.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        result.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        return result;
    }

    public Properties getProducerProperties() {
        // Use Kafka provided properties
        Properties result = new Properties();
        result.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        result.put("compression.type", "none");
        return result;
    }

    public Properties getServerProperties(int port) {
        // Use Kafka provided properties
        Properties result = new Properties();
        result.put("broker.id", "0");
        result.put("num.network.threads", "3");
        result.put("num.io.threads", "8");
        result.put("socket.send.buffer.bytes", "102400");
        result.put("socket.recv.buffer.bytes", "102400");
        result.put("num.partitions", "1");
        result.put("offset.topic.replication.factor", "1");
        result.put("transaction.state.log.replication.factor", "1");
        result.put("transaction.state.log.min.isr", "1");
        result.put("log.retention.hours", "168");
        result.put("log.segment.bytes", "1073741824");
        result.put("log.retention.check.interval.ms", "300000");
        result.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:" + port);
        result.put("zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms", "18000");
        result.put("group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms", "0");

        String path = "target/kafka-logs/run.";
        int index = 0;
        while (!Files.notExists(Paths.get(path + String.valueOf(index)))) {
            index += 1;
        }
        result.put("log.dirs", path + String.valueOf(index));
        return result;
    }

    public void printTopics(AdminClient admin, String inputTopic) throws Exception {
        Map<String, TopicDescription> topics = admin.describeTopics(Arrays.asList(inputTopic)).all().get();
        for (Map.Entry<String, TopicDescription> topic : topics.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("Topic:%s partitions=%d\n", topic.getValue().name(), topic.getValue().partitions().size());
            System.out.println(topic.getValue().toString());
        }
    }

    @ClassRule
    public static MiniClusterWithClientResource flinkCluster =
        new MiniClusterWithClientResource(
            new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
                .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(1)
                .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
                .build());

    @Test
    public void testFail() throws Exception {
        StringSerializer stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();
        StringDeserializer stringDeserializer = new StringDeserializer();
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);
        
        EmbeddedZookeeper zooKeeper = new EmbeddedZookeeper();
        KafkaServer server = TestUtils.createServer(new KafkaConfig(getServerProperties(zooKeeper.port())), new MockTime());
        AdminClient admin = AdminClient.create(getProducerProperties());

        String inputTopic = "input";

        Map<String, String> configs = new HashMap<>();
        int partitions = 1;
        short replication = 1;

        CreateTopicsResult result = admin.createTopics(Arrays.asList(
            new NewTopic(inputTopic, partitions, replication).configs(configs)
        ));
        result.all().get();

        printTopics(admin, inputTopic);

        // Some subscription events
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(getProducerProperties(), stringSerializer, stringSerializer);
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(inputTopic, 0, Time.days(1).toMilliseconds(), "0", "test message"));
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(inputTopic, 0, Time.days(10).toMilliseconds(), "0", "test message"));
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(inputTopic, 0, Time.days(100).toMilliseconds(), "0", "test message"));
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(inputTopic, 0, Time.days(1000).toMilliseconds(), "0", "test message"));
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(inputTopic, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE, "0", "test message"));
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();

        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> source = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>(inputTopic, new SimpleStringSchema(), getKafkaConsumerProperties());
        source.setStartFromEarliest();
        source.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
            new WatermarkStrategy<String>() {
                @Override
                public TimestampAssigner<String> createTimestampAssigner(TimestampAssignerSupplier.Context context) {
                    return new TimestampAssigner<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public long extractTimestamp(String event, long recordTimestamp) {
                            System.out.printf("Assigning timestamp %d\n", recordTimestamp);
                            return recordTimestamp;
                        }
                    };
                }

                @Override
                public WatermarkGenerator<String> createWatermarkGenerator(WatermarkGeneratorSupplier.Context context) {
                    return new WatermarkGenerator<String>() {
                        public long latestWatermark = Long.MIN_VALUE;

                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(String event, long timestamp, WatermarkOutput output) {
                            long eventWatermark = timestamp - Time.days(1).toMilliseconds();
                            if (eventWatermark > latestWatermark) {
                                System.out.printf("Emitting watermark %d\n", eventWatermark);
                                output.emitWatermark(new Watermark(eventWatermark));
                                latestWatermark = eventWatermark;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPeriodicEmit(WatermarkOutput output) {
                        }
                    };
                }
            });

        env.addSource(source)
            .process(new ProcessFunction<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public void processElement(String value, Context ctx, Collector<String> out) {
                    System.out.printf("Source ");
                    if (ctx != null) {
                        TimerService srv = ctx.timerService();
                        Long timestampLong = ctx.timestamp();
                        long timestamp = 0;
                        if (timestampLong != null) {
                            timestamp = timestampLong;
                        }
                        long watermark = 0;
                        if (srv != null) {
                            watermark = srv.currentWatermark();
                        }
                        System.out.printf("[timestamp=%d watermark=%d] ", timestamp, watermark);
                    }

                    System.out.println(value);
                    out.collect(value);
                }
            });

        System.out.println(env.getExecutionPlan());
        JobClient client = null;
        try {
            client = env.executeAsync("Fail Test");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

        printTopics(admin, inputTopic);

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        client.cancel().get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        try {
            server.shutdown();
            zooKeeper.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that Flink 1.12 defaults the TimeCharacteristic to EventTime and deprecates the whole TimeCharacteristic flow. So to downgrade to Flink 1.11, you must add the following statement to configure the StreamExecutionEnvironment.

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
```